# Converting Npx to [N/10]rem with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have php code that writes  a string, which is actually an html file,  to the server, but before the write I want to rip through and replace all "Npx" with "[N/10]rem".  So "width:203px" would become "width:20.3rem" and top:46px" would become "top:4.6rem". Does anyone see a regex string that will do  this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture the digit before `px` then match the string `px` and replace all the chars with `.$1rem`
. Where  `$1` refers to the characters which are present inside the group index 1.

```
(\d)px
```

Replacement string:

```
.$1rem
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dT6dN8/3)

```
$string = <<<EOT
width:203px
top:46px
top:6px
EOT;
$pattern = "~(\d)px~";
$replacement = ".$1rem";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

**Output:**

```
width:20.3rem
top:4.6rem
top:.6rem
```

Comment: One more thing.  Could you explain the "~" characters in the $pattern value?  Thanks.

Comment: @Steve regex must be included inside delimiters. `~` also consider as a delimiter. see http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Thanks. I had only seen / before.